# How to compress a bit string?

Tags: computer-networks, data-compression

I'm aware of some techniques to compress a string of characters such as Huffman coding. I need to know whether there is any technique to compress a long string of arbitrary bits? (ideally with high compression ratio).

Comment: What research have you done?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, including searching on this site, and on standard resources; and we expect you to show us in the question what research you've done.  For instance, Wikipedia has summary articles on compression, and we have many answers on the topic here.  So what research have you done?  What specifically are you confused about?  Right now your question is too broad -- one can write entire books on data compression, and people have.

Comment: @D.W. By the way I'm awar of some compressing techniques when the bit string has an spacial characteristic. e.g. :https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/changyu.dong/papers/pir.pdf            or http://cs.brown.edu/~jes/book/pdfs/ModelsOfComputation.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we could always compress a string of length $n$ bits to a string of length $n/2$ bits. Apply this compression algorithm $\log_2 n + 1$ times, and we have reduced a string of length $n$ bits into the empty string. But does the empty string really contain within itself all the information needed to reconstruct the original $n$ bit string?

More generally, a simple counting argument shows that *arbitrary strings cannot be compressed*. For any compression algorithm $C$:

1. For every $n$ we can find a string $x$ of length $n$ such that $|C(x)| \geq n$.
2. For every $n$, at least half the strings of length $n$ satisfy $|C(x)| \geq n-1$.
3. For every $n$, at least $1-1/n$ of the strings of length $n$ satisfy $|C(x)| \geq n-\log n$.

In particular, an "arbitrary" string cannot be compressed appreciably.

What are compression algorithms good for, then?

1. Many compression algorithms are *lossy*, that is, they actually throw away some of the information. This is the case with JPEG, MP3 and MPEG, for example. The compressed picture doesn't look quite the same, but it does look very similar. This property of pictures, that a picture can look similar while differing at the bit level, is exploited by lossy compression algorithms. These algorithms isolate the important parts of the data which are enough to cause in the viewer the same sensation as the original.
2. Some compression algorithms are *lossless* but are still able to compress their input. This is because the inputs are often not random and have structure which can be exploited. For example, HTML documents are extremely non-random: for one, they don't use the entire range of characters, but only alphanumeric characters and punctuation. Even raw sound files and pictures can be compressed appreciably, since music and images one would like to compress are not arbitrary white noise, but are smooth in various ways.

After you have compressed a file once, you don't expect it to be compressible again. The aim of a good compression algorithm is to achieve a random looking output, which in particular usually cannot be compressed, as we've seen above.

There are many lossy and lossless compression algorithms out there. If you're looking for lossless compression, you can try some of them out. Many are implemented as standalone tools such as ZIP and BZIP2. Lossy compression strongly depends on the type of medium you are trying to compress. Again, standalone tools are usually available for your perusal.